# pysimplegui put the images in a certain location

Tags: pysimplegui

is it possible to change the position of an image or a button?
I would need to set them an x ​​and y of my choice and not just centered right or left

I would like to put an image in a certain position

for example in this simple program how do I put the image in a certain point?

```
 import PySimpleGUI as sg
    
    GREEN = 'carrozina.png'
    ORANGE = 'cerchio-rosso.png'
    RED = 'cerchio-verde.png'
    
    layout = [
                [sg.Image(GREEN,   key='_IMAGE_')],
                [sg.Image(GREEN)],
                [sg.Button('Green'), sg.Button('Red'), sg.Button('Orange')]
             ]
    
    window = sg.Window('My new window', layout)
    
    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event is None:
            break
        if event == 'Green':
            file = GREEN
        elif event == 'Red':
            file = RED
        if event == 'Orange':
            file = ORANGE
        window.Element('_IMAGE_').Update(file)

window.Close()
```

Comment: It's possible to put element to any place, but not by PySimpleGUI code. In PySimpleGUI, you can only put image at any place, like (x, y), in sg.Graph.

Comment: ok and how can i do with x and y

Comment: In sg.Graph ? `figure = window['-Graph-'].draw_image(filename=None, data=None, location=(x, y))` for new image, `window['-Graph-'].move_figure(figure, dx, dy)` for relative movement, or `window['-Graph-'].relocate_figure(figure, x, y)` for absolute movement.

Comment: OK, all right.
but it's still not clear to me.
can't you give me an example with a code?

Comment: How about this ? https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Graph_Elem_Image_Album.py

Comment: I updated the initial question with a code example

Comment: There's nothing shown about the location (x, y) ? It cannot clearly show what you want in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to demo how to draw and move figure on sg.Graph.

You can use left/right/up/down key to move the figure, but without auto repeat function.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

width, height = size = (640, 480)
step = 20
steps = {'Left:37':(-step, 0), 'Right:39':(+step, 0), 'Up:38':(0, +step), 'Down:40':(0, -step)}

w, h = 56, 56
data = sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LAUGH

layout = [[sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, background_color='green', key='Graph')]]
window = sg.Window('My new window', layout, finalize=True, return_keyboard_events=True)

graph = window['Graph']
x , y = (width-w)//2, (height+h)//2
figure = graph.draw_image(data=data, location=(x, y))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event in ('Left:37', 'Right:39', 'Up:38', 'Down:40'):
        dx, dy = steps[event]
        x, y = max(0, min(width-w, x+dx)), max(h, min(height, y+dy))
        graph.relocate_figure(figure, x, y)

window.close()
```

Comment: how do i put the images i want for example: GREEN = 'carrozina.png'

Comment: For file, you can use option `filename` in method `draw_image`. For example, `figure = graph.draw_image(filename=GREEN, location=(x, y))`, make sure the provided path is correct to find the file.

Comment: HOW DO I IMPLEMENT IMAGE CHANGE OPERATION BASED ON BUTTON PRESSING

Comment: For button-clicked event: 1. call method `delete_figure(figure)` to delete figure if figure exists. 2. `figure = graph.draw_image(filename=RED, location=(x, y))` to draw a new one figure. You can check it by `if figure is not None:` and figure with initial value `None`.